# Understanding the proof of lemma 1.1 from Fisher, Marsden, and Moncrief's paper

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

The following lemma is from Fisher, Marsden, and Moncrief's paper: the structure of the space of solutions of Einstein's equations:<sup>1</sup>

**1.1. Lemma.**

If Ein( $\left.{ }^{(4)} g\right)=0$, and ${ }^{(4)} h$ is any symmetric two tensor, then
$$
\delta\left[\operatorname{DEin}\left({ }^{(4)} g\right) \cdot ^{4} h\right]=0
$$
where $\delta=\delta_{(4) g}$ is the divergence with respect to ${ }^{(4)} g$.

They gave the following proof:

The contracted Bianchi identities assert that $\delta \operatorname{Ein}\left({ }^{(4)} g\right)=0$. Differentiation gives the identity
$$
**\left[\text { D } \delta\left({ }^{(4)} g\right) \cdot ^{4}h\right] \cdot \operatorname{Ein}\left({ }^{(4)} g\right)+\delta\left[D \operatorname{Ein}\left({ }^{(4)} g\right) \cdot^{4} h\right]=0**
$$
where $\delta\left({ }^{(4)} g\right)=\delta_{(4)}$ indicates the functional dependence of $\delta$ on ${ }^{(4)} g$, and $\left[\mathrm{D} \delta\left({ }^{(4)} g\right) \cdot ^{4} \mathrm{h}\right]$ is the linearized divergence operator acting on Ein $\left({ }^{(4)} g\right)$. The lemma follows since $\operatorname{Ein}\left({ }^{(4)} g\right)=0$.

Sadly, I cannot see how they found the identity in the second sentence of the proof. Could you give me some hints/suggestions on how to derive the identity in the second sentence of Lemma 1.1?

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks so much.

<sup>1</sup>*Fischer, Arthur E.; Marsden, Jerrold E.; Moncrief, Vincent*, [**The structure of the space of solutions of Einstein’s equations. I: One Killing field**](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AIHPA_1980__33_2_147_0), Ann. Inst. Henri Poincaré, Nouv. Sér., Sect. A 33, 147-194 (1980); [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/76090). [ZBL0454.53044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0454.53044), [MR605194](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=605194).

Comment: You should include the statements and formulas in your question.

Comment: @DeaneYang I'm sorry for the confusion. Please note that by formula, I mean the derivative of the Einstein tensor in the h direction.

Comment: I don’t see any formulas in your question at all.

Comment: Perhaps images are blocked; that's why it's better to include them as [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959) (our equivalent of LaTeX).

Comment: @Glorfindel, I'll Latex. Thanks.

Comment: The title of you question has zero information. It should give at least some hint what the question is abut.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Could you see the formula now?

Comment: I suggest writing everything using indices.

Comment: Thank you so much @DeaneYang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the formula you are asking about is the long one highlighed by $*$ $*$ in your question, while the standard "contracted Bianchi identity" $\delta \operatorname{Ein}\left({ }^{(4)} g\right)=0$ poses no mystery to you. The Longer equation is simply obtained by using the Leibniz rule while applying the functional derivative $\mathrm{D}$ that last identity. I would consider that a pretty clear explanation, but possibly that is not the point you are confused about.

Perhaps you are wondering why the Leinbniz rule applies to $\delta$, which is an operator. A quick way to see why is just to write the corresponding expression in coordinates. There is no need to be very explicit, the following schematic form suffices:
$$
  \delta \mathrm{Ein} = \partial \cdot \mathrm{Ein} + \Gamma \cdot \mathrm{Ein} .
$$
That is, the covariant divergence operator $\delta(-)$ consists of a coordinate derivative part $\partial\cdot(-)$ and of the part containing multiplication by Christoffel symbols $\Gamma\cdot(-)$. Unsurprisingly, the coordinate derivative part has no dependence on the metric, hence formally $\mathrm{D}\partial = 0$. So $\mathrm{D}\delta$ comes entirely from the Christoffel part, which quite obviously obeys the Leibniz rule.

If that's still not where your confusion lies, please clarify your question further.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Yes, you answered my question.